# AngularJS and Stripe: Send token to server, insert the token into the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, stripe.net

I am working on a card processing API with ASP.NET , HTML , AngularJS and Stripe.NET. I am pretty new to all of them. 
I followed the documentation on the Stripe website for sending the Stripe token to the server (here): https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#card-validateCardNumber

It worked! However, instead of JQuery I want to use AngularJS. I want to convert from JQuery to AngularJS this part of the JQuery code:

```
Stripe.card.createToken({
   number: $('.card-number').val(),
   cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
   exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
   exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val(),
   address_zip: $('.address_zip').val()
}, stripeResponseHandler);


function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

  // Grab the form:
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) { // Problem!

  // Show the errors on the form
  $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
  $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

  } else { // Token was created!

  // Get the token ID:
  var token = response.id;

  // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
  $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

  // Submit the form:
  $form.get(0).submit();

  }
 }
```

If someone can help, I will appreciate it a lot. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my question (a while ago, just finding some time to answer it in here).
Firstly, here are the tips:

1. Use "angular-payments.js". You can find it here: https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments

You have to use the html syntax for the card details as in the documentation of the repository.

2. It is not the same as in the Stripe documentation. I have used AngularJS service so that I can pass my token to my ASP.NET application.
3. Thirdly, I had problems with the verification token - here is a nice post for how to handle it: http://blog.novanet.no/anti-forgery-tokens-using-mvc-web-api-and-angularjs/

Here is (part of) my (AngularJS) code:

```
(function () {
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ["angularPayments"]);

        app.service('Service', function ($http) {
            this.AddCard = function (stripeToken, stripeEmail) {
                var tokenData = {
                    "stripeToken": stripeToken,
                    "stripeEmail": stripeEmail
                };

                $http.post("http://localhost:48484/payment/card", tokenData).success(function (response) {
                    window.location = '/cardprocess/confirmation';
                })
            };
        });

        app.directive('ncgRequestVerificationToken', ['$http', function ($http) {
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $http.defaults.headers.common['RequestVerificationToken'] = attrs.ncgRequestVerificationToken || "no request verification token";
            };
        }]);

        app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', myCtrl]);
        app.controller("buyCtrl", function ($scope, CardService) {

            $scope.submit = function () {
                $scope.processing = true;
            }

            $scope.stripeFormSubmit = function (code, result) {
                $scope.processing = false;
                $scope.hideAlerts();
                if (result.error) {
                    $scope.stripeError = result.error.message;
                } else {
                    //$scope.stripeToken = result.id;
                    $scope.stripeToken = result.id;
                    CardService.AddCard($scope.stripeToken, $scope.stripeEmail);
                }
            };

            $scope.hideAlerts = function () {
                $scope.stripeError = null;
                $scope.stripeToken = null;
            };
        });

     }());
```

(The html page is quite big so I decided not to put in here. It should be straight forward - I have a form, which calls AngularJS model "stripeFormSubmit".)

4. Finally, you can see the "CardService", which is talking to my api - the service is initialised at the begining of the paste code.

That is the main idea. I decided not to go in a lot of detail. But I will try to answer questions (if any).